# Timeseries data aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have timeseries metrics about memory usage by processes. Here are the fields:

```
<date>, <user>, <processid>, <memoryMB>
```

Here  by  takes  at time  .

```
1, foo, 1, 100
1, foo, 2, 500
2, foo, 3, 100
2, bar, 4, 100
```

What is the best way to find out peak memory usage by any user in last 15 days?

Here is query with aggregation, which adds the memoryMB by user at every time instant, then I post process the output to get the max memoryMB.

```
{
    "from":0,
    "size":0,
    "query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"date":{"gte":"now-15d"}}}]}},
    "aggs": {
        "name": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user",
                "size": 1000
            },
            "aggs": {
                "date": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "date",
                        "order" : { "_term" : "asc" },
                        "size": 15000
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "mb": {
                            "sum": { "field": "memoryMB" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
-Soumitra.

Comment: Why don't you use a `date_histogram` aggregation on your `date` field instead of `terms`?

Comment: I would also suggest Timelion: https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-timeline https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/timelion.html

Comment: date_histrogram won't work, since there are different processes running by the same user, and all the samples at the same time by the same user has to added first, then max of that would be the peak memory usage.